# Collect Maximum month data

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I need to collect data from the database
based on the last month creation.

[image]

**In my case**

a. month_val is individual month

b. cur_month is last updated month

Each month(cur_month) my users can update data for any months(month_val).

**Example output:**

[image]

The query should return only Last month data.

On January month (cur_month 1) I have added data for Jan,Feb which is month_val 1,2

On February month (cur_month 2) I have added data for Feb,Mar which is month_val 2,3

...

On December month (cur_month 12) I have added data for Mar which is month_val 3.

[image]

Based on this stored data. I have to collect latest(marked green) month_val based on cur_month

Hope I have explained my problem clearly.

I tried in this way

```
SELECT * FROM proj_duration_map where cur_month=max(cur_month)
```

Badly it doesn't work

Comment: Which database are you using, MySQL or SQL Server?

Comment: Do you mean that the query can retrieve the latest cur_month?

For example, year_val & cur_month = '2016-12'.

Comment: This would appear to be a poor choice of date column(s) strategy

Comment: What's the use of the field "last_updated"? Also do you want the results for the maximum cur_month with or without taking into account the year_val?

Comment: last_updated is just for logging purpose. I need cur_month for each year

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should `GROUP BY` 4 first columns.

In `MSSQL`, you can use `ROW_NUMBER` to choose `MAX` `MONTH`

```
SELECT * FROM
(
   SELECT
      *,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY pid, week_val, month_val, year_val 
                        ORDER BY cur_month DESC) AS RN
   FROM proj_duration_map
) AS A
WHERE RN = 1 --choose MAX cur_month (ORDER DESC)
```

In `MySQL`, you can use `COUNT` instead of `ROW_NUMBER`

```
SELECT * FROM (
   SELECT A.pid, A.week_val, A.month_val, A.year_val, A.cur_month,
          Count(*) as RN
   FROM proj_duration_map A
   INNER JOIN proj_duration_map B
      ON A.pid = B.pid
         AND A.week_val = B.week_val
         AND A.month_val = B.month_val
         AND A.year_val = B.year_val
         AND A.cur_month >= B.cur_month
   GROUP BY A.pid, A.week_val, A.month_val, A.year_val, A.cur_month
) AS C
WHERE RN = 1
```

Comment: If he uses MySQL, the analytical function partition by is not supported

Comment: You can GROUP BY month_val, year_val

Comment: above mysql query doesn't run on my db

Comment: @ Nguyễn Hải Triều You solved my problem. Small changes done in your answer. your query missed one comma and it returned smallest cur_months. That I have corrected. Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT month_val, year_val, cur_month FROM proj_duration_map
  where cur_month=max(cur_month)
   group by month_val, year_val, cur_month
```

Field list in SELECT must be the same as that of GROUP BY.

Comment: your query returns only December(12) month data,I need all the latest data.